# Remapping Oceans with Tectonic Shifts

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, terraforming

Let's say you have a narrow section of ocean (relatively narrow) and you want to raise it up above the water.  Would it be possible to do this by messing with the tectonic plates--say, tipping one like a see-saw so that the floor of the ocean lifted up sufficiently?

This would be accomplished with fairly advanced technology, say something out of Star Trek.  Nukes dropped in the right places and so on.

I'm just having trouble imagining how you would go about doing that and how the physics would work.  Obviously there would be a lot of earthquakes and tidal waves to accompany it, but I'm more thinking of how the plate would interact with the molten material below it, and the other plates, and so on.

Comment: Tectonic plates don't "tilt". To raise ocean floor above sea level you squeeze it between two colliding plates. (And anyway, you still won't get oceanic crust above sea level, except in exceptional circumstances, e.g., Iceland.) Look at the evolution of the [Tethys Ocean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethys_Ocean) (and specifically the [Paratethys Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paratethys), it matches exactly the question), for example. The Alps and the Himalayas were once at the bottom of the sea...

Comment: What time frame were you considering for this operation?

Comment: Tectonic plates are the exception rather than the rule. They are not a requirement for a planet.Therefore, you can make them as big or as small as you want. A tectonic plate the size of the chunk of land you want to raise, and subject it to internal pressure changes of the planet. If you want it cyclic, have it rise with the alignment of other planets, like a tide.A bit of a stretch, but we don't understand all of the geology of Mars. We are still finding surprises on the moons of Saturn. Or the small section of plate could be squeezed and unsqueezed by other larger plates, like Arctic ice.

Comment: What you're looking for is a [subduction zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subduction).

Comment: is there a reason you cannot just fill it in with rubble and earth? We can build islands after all.

Comment: @John Bit of a scale problem to fill an entire ocean.

Comment: not compared to altering a tectonic plate, if you have the technology to consider shifting a tectonic plate moving a bunch of rock around is child's play. You are talking about orders of magnitude less material and energy.

Comment: How "narrow" is this section of seafloor/land/tectonic plate? What's its total size/area?

Comment: @Slarty Hours, if possible, maybe 24 hours on the outside.

Comment: @JustinThyme Huh.  It's not intended to be cyclic, but the use of other planets' gravity is interesting.  What alternatives are there to tectonic plates?  Any good writeups anywhere?

Comment: @John I had considered filling it with rubble and earth, but I'd like something A) more dramatic, B) faster.  I'm looking for some sort of force multiplier that would bring forward the timeline considerably.  Dramatically tilting a tectonic plate with nuclear weapons or something seemed to fit the bill.  Chopping up several mountains and shoving them into the gap might also suffice, but I feel like that's a last resort from a storytelling perspective.

Comment: @HDE226868 For the sake of reducing the difficulty of the task, the intended gap could be as narrow as the Strait of Gibraltar; I would prefer a little wider though.  Does that help?

Comment: The trick is the difference in scale, even using every nuclear weapon on the planet trying to move a tectonic plate with them is like trying to move the empire state building by farting at it.

Comment: See [Gravity Moved Continents on Early Earth](https://www.livescience.com/47882-how-plate-tectonics-started.html) "For up to 150 million years, gravitational spreading could have driven early plate tectonics – it was getting the ball rolling for later plate tectonic activity."

Answer (score 4):

What you're talking about is an ocean [suturing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suture_(geology)) operation that produces an [ophiolite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophiolite). Basically, you'd need to heat the mantle "behind" the landmasses on either side of the sea.

You can do this with Star Trek technology, one because it's science fantasy, and two because they did something very similar on STNG and again in STV. Heating the mantle will push the land up and away from the new [spreading centres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seafloor_spreading) you create and force the seabed to [shorten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust_tectonics) either [subducting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subduction) or under going [orogenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orogeny) uplift. The ocean will eventually close leaving either a lens of seafloor sediments from the [accretionary wedges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretionary_wedge) from the seafloor margins, and/or ophiolic material, as a range of hills or mountains in the centre of the new landmass.

How long "eventually" is will depend how much heat you pump into the system and how big the landmasses you need to move are, you can't put the new spreading centres too far from the continental margins either or you'll get subduction on the wrong side of the landmasses you're trying to bring together. Real world examples of such the sutures that will form the central mountains include the [Urals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ural_Mountains) in Siberia.

As a note ophiolites are often enriched in economically important [hydrothermal minerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_circulation) including the copper ores in [Cyprus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus#Etymology) and [Bougainville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bougainville_Island).

For the record the amount of energy you're talking about putting into the planet in question is absolutely, phenomenally, ridiculous.

Comment: But it's Star Trek, so the energy comes from handwavium, and the heat you're adding is absorbed by unobtanium, and the ridiculous tsunamis, weather effects, etc. are stopped by some good old Plotium Devicide.

Comment: There's a lot of terminology in your answer, but I think I get it.  Let's take the Strait of Gibraltar as an example; if there was a fault line between them, by heating the crust in Spain or Morocco, depending on how the plates interlocked, I could speed up the subduction process and produce a ridge, potentially large enough to block the channel?  That sounds like what I'm looking for; do you know of anything, such as coincidental or environmental factors, that could be used to reduce the amount of energy needed for this?

Comment: @MattMc If you were accelerating an existing subduction system it would save you _some_ energy but you're talking about heating gigatonnes of rock, which is a good insulator, at depths of up to 50km, far enough to cause geographically significant thermal expansion, that takes a lot of power. In theory if you could put the energy directly into reducing the friction of the subduction fault and then give it a mechanical shove (probably with an explosion) you might shave a bit off the total power requirements. The thing to member is that planets are huge, and heavy, they have a lot of inertia.

Answer (score 3):

**How to do the Anti-Atlantis..**

OK, as phrased this question does not make much geologic sense..

But as my MSc project (written on a 486 in 1996, I'm a bit old, I doubt that a reference is available now), I was modelling the effect of phase transitions on density and in subducted rocks, which could change surface elevation. Essentially, as rocks go to higher-density forms under pressure, the surface can subside, and with some parameter-tweaking this effect could reach to over a kilometer of subsidence.

Coupled to this, we have the concept of [Earthquakes from Phase Transitions](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/004019516590034X). This is a real thing; rocks are moved out of their 'stability zone' but don't change mineral assemblage until there is an external shock, so it can happen quite suddenly.

So, in your scenario, some rocks have previously been compressed into dense mineral forms by overlying rocks, but these overlying rocks have been eroded away leaving them unstable and covered with water.  Then someone does something to destabilise these rocks and... Bang! They turn into less-dense mineral forms and you get a kilometer of uplift in a matter of minutes.

Comment: And devastate the planet, probably setting evolution (assuming there's reasonably advanced life) back a few hundred million years, but they do that in every other Star Trek episode anyway.

Comment: Wow, that's actually pretty genius.  Changing the density of the seafloor and thereby increasing its volume, raising it up?  Is there a way to do this without the necessity of a specifically and coincidentally unstable section of seafloor?

Comment: @Gryphon How would a few kilometers of phase transition devastate a planet?  The resulting tidal waves and earthquakes?  Certainly bad, but I feel like you're exaggerating.

Comment: I suppose I was.  It would be pretty bad though.

Answer (score 2):

**Sure....**

Yes you could technically do this

The Himalayan mountains contain rock from ancient seabeds so its certainly possible. Just like in Star Trek use the tractor beam.

**Here's reality:**

Messing with the techtonic plate will result in Earthquakes, tidal waves, and volcanoes. The intensity of these is multiplied by distance of the moved land mass (and we are talking centimeters).

Basically, the plate is cooled rock sitting on top of an ocean of lava called the mantle. In your case, where 2 plates get pushed together rock gets pushed up raising sea beds and creating mountains. However, in its wake volcanoes are formed creating new land on the other side. The faster the plate moves, the more volcanoes get created behind it.

**More realistically, they could just dump dirt in the sea and fill it up pushing the water elsewhere or into an underground system. Or they could drill a hole to the mantle and create volcano to fill in that area.**

All of which would be all around cheaper and less destructive than messing with the plate.

Comment: I'm aware that messing with tectonic plates would result in multiple coinciding catastrophes, and I'm fine with that.  In the specific scenario I'm building, the decision to perform this process is difficult but necessary.  I like the idea of drilling a hole in the mantle to create a volcano, and had considered it, but I was wondering if the lava wouldn't solidify before forming a mound of sufficient size?  How big a hole do you think would be needed to block something about 10 miles in width?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don’t think it’s really a practical idea at all. The oceanic plate is where it is for a good reason, it’s heavier than the water above it and lighter than the mantle rock below it.

Tectonic plates are far too massive to behave like see-saws, if a sufficiently massive force were applied it, it would simply break.

Even assuming that super high tech is involved that could provide sufficient energy, the application of such a huge amount of energy would almost certainly manifest itself as heat and destroy the oceanic plate that you are attempting to lift by melting it.

Sadly the probable reason why you are having trouble imagining this is because it is not possible. Instead of thinking of a see-saw, think of a large slab of clay (the mantle) with a sheet of paper (the crust) glued to it.